# How to get value from foreach table td using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table built through making view from an MVC controller. Spits out a bunch of rows.

I have an ajax call that submits data to a controller for data input. I need the first td of the selected column.

I am able to accomplish this when only row exists, but when I add a second row, the call pulls in the value from the row above and the selected row.

I only want the one value(Id) of that specific row.

Here is the table.

```
<table class="table  table-striped table-hover  col-xl-12" id="policyTable">
<tr class="thead-dark">
    <th class="toggleMe1">
        UnderWriter
    </th>
    <th class="toggleMe2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Client)
    </th>

    <th>
        Exp-Policies
    </th>

    <th>
        Exp-Date
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr id="id_@item.Id">

        <td class="hideMe">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NewUw)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Expiring_Policies)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExpDate)

        <td style="width: 25%; height: 120px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                @* @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.Notes, new { @class = "form-control textAreaCS", @rows = 8 })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 ml-3">
                <div class="row">
                   @* <input type="submit" value="Save" id="notes" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm col-2" style="font-size: 16px" />*@

                    <div class="col-12">
                        @if (TempData["SM"] != null)
                        {
                            <div class="alert alert-success text-center text-capitalize" style="font-size: 16px;">
                                @TempData["SM"]
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
                @Html.ActionLink("Review", "EditPolicy", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "review" })
            </button>
           <br/>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ColumnModal">
                Notes
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here is the Jquery I use to capture the values I need

```
 $('#ColumnModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

                //find the correct Id associated with the row. 
                var id = $('td:first-child').text();
                var policyNotes = $("#textForNotes").focus();
                //var id = $('td:first-child').text();
                var comment = $.trim($("modal#textForNotes").val());
                $('#submit').on('click', function () {

                    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'Id': id, 'polNotes': $('#textForNotes').val() });
                    console.log(id + $('#textForNotes').val()); 



                   /* Commented out for simplicity 
                      $.ajax({
                        url: '/Policy/CompletedNotes',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: data,
                        success: function () {
                            //alert('success');
                            console.log('success');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //alert('Error');
                            console.log('Error');
                        }
                    })
                    */
                   // location.reload();

                });


            })
```

I have a modal that comes up and captures the Id and some text. It captures one row by itself just fine. With multiple rows it does not. How do I isolate the value capture to that specific rows first td?

EDIT:

I have tried multiple Jquery finds to accomplish this. Everything returns the value above. Here's one .. and many variations of it.

```
var id = $('#policyTable tr').find(' td:first-child').text();
```

ADDITIONAL CONTENT FROM BROWSER TO SHOW OUTPUT:

I currently have three rows that show up in the table. So it captures all three Id's and prints them out to the console

```
CompletedPolicies:488 
            359 //row 1

            471 // row 2 .. I clicked on this one

            474 // row 3
        This is just a test
```

I have an additional test I ran, but it captures everything in the rows. Wasn't really useful

Comment: I guess that this is just a JQuery thing, can you just paste the resulting code (from your browser) in here? So we can run it on Plunker

Comment: Sure.. I have a few of them. so just a moment.. it will be long on the edit

Comment: It's now up Hassen Ch.

Comment: `$('#policyTable tr')` is getting ALL rows when you just want a single row

Comment: zgood. Even without it, still does the same thing. var id = $('tr td:first-child').text(); Or var id = $('td:first-child').text(); All three bring back the same result.  Doesn't matter though. I found another solution to it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var id = $('#policyTable tr').children('td')[0].text();
```

I think it's work.

Comment: Doflamingo19, thanks for the help,  but it comes back with this error. "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).children(...)[0].text is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

So, I was not able to secure a reasonable solution going about it the way I did above. On a whim, I tried something from a previous project. I knew if I could only isolate the value I wanted I would be able to do everything else I needed. So, rather than use a button to call the modal, then capture the unknown row Id (which I think is what was happening. it didn't know which value to specifically capture.) I make the row itself clickable. And call the modal upon that click instead. From there I am able to isolate the values I need. I make the  within the foreach a class of "clickable-row". Here is the Jquery call I make after it is clicked. Which captures all I need.

```
 $('#policyTable').on('click', '.clickable-row', function (event) {

           //Capture the row Id 
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();

            //Listen for modal button to be clicked
            $('#ColumnModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {

                var policyNotes = $("#textForNotes").focus();

                var comment = $.trim($("modal#textForNotes").val());

                //Listen for submit button. Then send AJAX .post call to controller
                $('#submit').on('click', function () {

                    var data = JSON.stringify({ 'Id': id, 'polNotes': $('#textForNotes').val() });
                    console.log(id + $('#textForNotes').val());
                     $.ajax({
                         url: '/Policy/CompletedNotes',
                         type: 'POST',
                         contentType: 'application/json',
                         data: data,
                         success: function () {
                             //alert('success');
                             console.log('success');
                         },
                         error: function () {
                             //alert('Error');
                             console.log('Error');
                         }
                     })
                     location.reload();

                });


            })



            /*  $.get(url, Id, function (data) {
                  $(".content").html(data);
                  alert("your id is " + data);
              })*/
        })
```